# Using Jquery, mysql, and php I need the results of one dropdown select to alter the choices in a second dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, chained

I have 2 dropdown select boxes in my form.  The first one allows the user to choose a car make "vmake".  Once a vmake is chosen a "vmodel" select box appears from thin air and then the user can choose the vmodel.  However, I want the vmodel box to be there on page load, so it doesnt just appear out of thin air.  It would be empty if the user tries to open it until they select a vmake.  Heres my html

```
<select name="vmake" id="vmake">
<option value"" selected="selected">Make</option>
<?php getTierOne()l ?>
</select>

<select name="vmodel" id="vmodel">
<option value"" selected="selected">Model</option>
</select>
<span id="wait_1"></span>
<span id="result_1"></span>
```

Heres the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#wait_1').show();
$('#vmake').change(function(){
$('#wait_1').show();
$('#result_1').hide();
$.get("func.php", {
func" "vmake",
drop_varL $('#vmake').val()
}, function(response){
$('#result_1').fadeOut();
setTimeout(finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
});
return false;
]);
});
```

lastly the php which connects to my database

```
function getTierOne()
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINT vmake FROM vmake")
or die(mysql_error());
while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{ echo '<option value="'.tier['vmake'].'">'.$tier['vmake'].'</option>';
}}

if($_GET['func'] == "vmake" && isset ($_GET['func'])) {
vmake($_GET['drop_var']);}
function vmake($drop_var)
{ include_once('db.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vmake WHERE vmake='$drop_var'")
or die(mysql_error());

echo '<option value=" " selected="selected">Model</option>';

while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result))
{ echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['vmodel'].'">'.$drop_2['vmodel'].'</option>';
}}
```

I got some help with the original code form an open source website and now I just need to change it a little to make it do what I want.  As it stands it will create a new vmodel select box next to the existing one, but I just want it to populate the select box that appears on page load.  Any help is very much appreciated.  Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using jQuery [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Example:

```
$('#vmodel').load('func.php',{vmake:$('#vmake').val()});
```

Would need to change the PHP as well, so you make a normal array of values and then send it through [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).